# Order records if it is in the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `contents` table.

```
+------------+------+----------+
| content_id | year | has_file |
+------------+------+----------+
| 1          | 2017 | true     |
| 2          | 2018 | true     |
| 3          | 2016 | true     |
| 4          | 2018 | true     |
| 5          | 2018 | false    |
+------------+------+----------+
```

Then I have the `uploads` table.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | content_id | filename   |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2          | sample.jpg |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I want to fetch the data according to the latest year then followed by if it has a file.

I can do it using the query `SELECT * FROM contents ORDER BY year DESC, has_file DESC`.

The problem is not all records with `has_file` set to `true` has actually recorded on the `uploads` table.

Is can exclude all records that do not exist on the other table by adding `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM uploads WHERE uploads.content_id = contents.content_id)`.

But I don't want to exclude it, I just want it to appear last and the records with files appear first. Is this possible?

Expected result:

```
+------------+------+----------+
| content_id | year | has_file |
+------------+------+----------+
| 2          | 2018 | true     |
| 4          | 2018 | true     |
| 5          | 2018 | false    |
| 1          | 2017 | true     |
| 3          | 2016 | true     |
+------------+------+----------+
```

Comment: With that table data, whart is the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh I added expected result.

Comment: Can you try something like this. `select c.* from contents c left outer join uploads u on c.content_id=u.content_id order by u.content_id,c.year;` My intuition is that the left outer join will give a NULL for the non existent rows and you will be able to easily make them appear at the last.

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match your requirements. *the data according to the latest year*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the `EXISTS` clause to the `ORDER BY` clause of your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contents 
ORDER BY year DESC, 
         has_file DESC, 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM uploads WHERE uploads.content_id = contents.content_id) DESC
```

Output:

```
content_id  year    has_file
2           2018    true
4           2018    true
5           2018    false
1           2017    true
3           2016    true
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa2530/1)

Comment: that's a really neat way to do that. looks simpler compared to the outer join suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well,

```
SELECT 
    id, year, has_file
FROM
    (SELECT 
        c.id,
            c.year,
            c.has_file,
            CASE
                WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                ELSE 2
            END AS flag
    FROM
        contents c
    LEFT JOIN uploads u ON (c.id = u.content_id)) tmp
ORDER BY flag , year DESC;
```